# Missing "Requirement" work item type in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am not able to add a work item of type "Requirement". I was following this example in the video [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VisualStudio/Requirements-Management-and-Traceability-with-Visual-Studio-Team-System-2010) and found that my list of work Items is different from what they have in the video there. I thought maybe that person had created some custom work items so I tried checking out [other links](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eranruso/archive/2009/12/30/tfs-2010-work-items-basic-user-guide-create-new-work-items.aspx) and found that a work item of type "Requirement" is in the default work item types.

However, in my TFS installation I see only these:

[image]

As you can see, the "Requirement" type is missing. Is this because I have not done something right in the installation of TFS or the creation of the project in TFS? All the projects in my TFS are currently using the MS Agile project template. All of them have only the above work item types. When I looked further into the video; all the forms for entering work item details looks different from what I have in my installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Requirement work item type is from the CMMI Template... Since you are using the Agile Template, it is called a "User Story". The have the same role in your project.  The are different in that the "User Story" has less fields and the states are different.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan said you are using the agile template, it's the default template if new team projects are created.

You can change that in the dialog where you select your team project template like shown 
[here](http://www.google.de/imgres?q=new%20team%20project&um=1&hl=de&sa=N&biw=1349&bih=672&tbm=isch&tbnid=FFvS8oS89Mi33M%3a&imgrefurl=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187319%28v=vs.80%29.aspx&docid=7waOWh6JZfgbLM&imgurl=http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC113530.gif&w=480&h=351&ei=6voIUPSmE6iu0QWa34G6Cg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=837&vpy=10&dur=1186&hovh=192&hovw=263&tx=157&ty=86&sig=100629665554333613449&page=3&tbnh=144&tbnw=197&start=40&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:40,i:227)